# Ubuntu 13.04 is not installing after installing windows 7(dual boot)

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I am using Lenovo G580 series which came with default Linux system. I installed windows 7 on my machine and left `100GB` space unallocated for installing `Ubuntu 13.04`. After installing windows I am not able to use unallocated space on my `HDD` to install `Ubuntu`.

Please give me some solution how can I installing both OS, or is there any dependency with windows 7 which is not allowing me to install Ubuntu.

I am using bootable `USB` to install `Ubuntu`

Comment: We need more details. Did you try formatting the unallocated space to ext4? You can use Gparted for that from a live CD session.

Comment: @AwalGarg... No I did not format that space. Please tell me what is Gparted and how to use.

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu Live CD or USB ready?

Comment: Bootable USB...

Comment: Boot in to Ubuntu Live session. When you see the GUI, you can goto Dash (the nice icon at top left corner) and search for Gparted.

Comment: @AwalGarg... I tried but not found any luck. Any other reason you think, please let me know

Comment: What happened when you opened Gparted? Did you successfully format it into ext4?